# Why no rule for un-collapsing margins

Tags: css, margin

There are circumstances under which elements' vertical margins will collapse. Sometimes the author doesn't want this to happen, and I understand that the only way to "un-collapse" margins is to:

- Set a `border` sized >= `1px`
- Set a `padding` sized >= `1px`

These workarounds make sense to me, but they are just that: *workarounds*, and they have drawbacks. I'm surprised that there's not some kind of css3 property like `margin-collapse: none;`, similar to `border-collapse`.

Is it really true that setting a border/padding is the only way to uncollapse margins?

Comment: Can you give an example of collapsing margins? I haven't heard of them before.

Comment: If you add any padding to an object, it's margins will not be collapsed.

Comment: @Blender - Read this: http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are numerous other ways, including floating, clearance, absolute positioning, setting `overflow` to values other than `visible`, setting a certain `min-height`, etc, which you can determine based on what the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) says.

But you're right in that all of these are workarounds with various side effects and disadvantages, and there is no true "off switch" available in CSS like `margin-collapse`, not even in the CSS3 Box Model module. A possible rationale is that margin collapse is supposed to happen naturally, and therefore the only way it can be prevented is as a side effect, but that's just my guess, as I agree there are several cases where it isn't intuitive or appropriate.

That said, if you're feeling adventurous you could make a suggestion on the [www-style mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style), and see what they say. I don't think you're going to have much luck, though.